# Use an excel form to create multiple rows

Tags: excel, forms

I'm trying to find a microsoft solution to my problem. I need to create a form that will create multiple rows when a response is submitted. For example I want the form to have date and warehouse and then for people to be able to enter multiple SKUs. I want the date and warehouse to fill column 1 and 2 respectively and then SKU to be in column 3 with a new row created for each SKU entry.

Everything I see in building forms only creates one row with multiples columns for each SKU.

Is there a way I can do this in microsoft forms or excel forms? I've scoured forums and google, but with no luck.

Comment: You could have a userform with textboxes for the date, warehouse and SKUs. The user could enter multiple SKUs as a delimited string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Would that work with excel online? I'm trying to find a solution that's web-accessible.